# Error: cannot convert from node* to node c++?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm a beginner in c++ and I'm creating my own InterlacedList class for a school project and I've created a Node class:

```
#include "Node.h"
#include "Student.h"
#include <string>

Node::Node()
{
     this->student = nullptr;
     this->nextName = nullptr;
     this->nextYear = nullptr;
     this->nextGrade = nullptr;
}

Student Node::getStudent()
{
    return this->student;
}

Node Node::getNextName()
{
    return this->nextName;
}

Node Node::getNextYear()
{
    return this->nextYear;
}

Node Node::getNextGrade()
{
    return this->nextGrade;
}
```

Which compiles fine.

But in my InterlacedList class:

```
#include "InterlacedList.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include "Student.h"

InterlacedList::InterlacedList()
{
    this->head = nullptr;
    this->tail = nullptr;
}

Node InterlacedList::getHead()
{
    return this->head;
}

Node InterlacedList::getTail()
{
    return this->tail;
}
```

I receive this errors:
could not convert ‘((model::InterlacedList*)this)->model::InterlacedList::head’ from ‘model::Node*’ to ‘model::Node’

AND

error: could not convert ‘((model::InterlacedList*)this)->model::InterlacedList::tail’ from ‘model::Node*’ to ‘model::Node’

My understanding is it should work just as the Node classes getters work. 
Please Help.

Comment: `return *(this->head)` is what you should write, or change the function so it returns a pointer to Node.

Comment: If you're going to return the Node, it's better to return a reference to it. Also remember to check for nullptr before dereferencing the pointer.

Comment: Thank you that fixed it. But how and why?

Comment: As an aside, are you absolutely sure that you want a complicated interface between your list and its nodes making everything at least twice as complex, thrice as verbose, and likely inefficient as well? Better to put it all into the list-class directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your `InterlacedList::InterlacedList()`, it seems both `head` and `tail` are defined as pointers. Your `getHead()` returns a Node, **not** a pointer to Node, that's why the error pops up: you forgot to dereference it.

You can change the function so it returns a pointer (don't forget to change the class definition in header files):

```
Node* InterlacedList::getHead()
```

or return the dereferenced object:

```
return *(this->head);
```

but be sure to check for nullptr before doing the latter. Also if you do this, it's better to return a reference to the Node instead of returning a copy.

Comment: @CalebF. You definitely forgot to change the header files.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the definition of `Node`. You forgot to show it in the question, but my crystal ball told me that it looks something like this:

> ```
> class Node {
>     // something ...
>     Node* head;
>     Node* tail;
>     // something ...
> };
> ```

Pay particular attention to the types of `Node::head` (and `Node::tail`). The type is `Node*`. That means a *pointer to `Node`*.

Next take a look at the declaration of `getHead` (and `getTail`):

> ```
> Node InterlacedList::getHead()
> ```

Pay particular attention to the return type of the function. It is `Node`. That is different from `Node*`. This return type means that the function returns a new `Node` object. It doesn't return a pointer.

Next take a look at the definition of `getHead` (and `getTail`):

> ```
> return this->head;
> ```

Well, you're trying to return a `Node*` from a function that is supposed to return a `Node`. A pointer is (typically) not implicitly convertible to its pointed type. The error is quite clear about this:

> ```
> could not convert .. from ‘model::Node*’ to ‘model::Node’
> ```

Solution: Return an object whose type matches the return type of the function. One possible solution is to indirect the pointer:

```
return *this->head;
```

Another is to change the return type of the function to match the pointer that you are returning. Consider which solution was the one that you attempted to implement.

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I had your crystal ball was accurate. That helps a ton.